# Populating dropdown menu with data from sqlite database in flutter

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am working on a list app and want to load the categories of tasks of the home page in the dropdown menu button.

I have used SQflite to save the categories in a table.

When I tap the Dropdown Menu, the values seem not to be loaded on the menu. It's just an empty list.

Here is the code:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  TodoService _todoService;
  var _selectedValue;

  var _categories = List<DropdownMenuItem>();

  List<Todo>_todoList=List<Todo>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalKey=GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
   
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    getAllTodos();
  }
  _loadCategories() async {
    var _categoryService = CategoryService();
    var categories = await _categoryService.readCategory();
    categories.forEach((category) {
      setState(() {
        _categories.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(category['name']),
          value: category['name'],
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  getAllTodos()async{
    _todoService=TodoService();
    _todoList=List<Todo>();

    var todos= await _todoService.readTodo();

    todos.forEach((todo){
      setState(() {
        var model=Todo();
        model.id=todo['id'];
        model.title=todo['title'];
        model.dueDate=todo['dueDate'];
        model.category=todo['category'];
        model.isFinished=todo['isFinished'];
        _todoList.add(model);
      });
    });
  }
 
 


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _globalKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          DropdownButton(
            value: _selectedValue,
            items: _categories,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedValue = value;
                _loadCategories();
              });
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Did you try to call _loadCategories inside the initState method?

Comment: Yes,did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the service calls?
Maybe, the SQFlite database is not populated with the values you are trying to retrieve.

Try with a dummy set of values first, like:

```
items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
```

If the above works, make sure you populate the table by calling an `insert` query via the service call.

Or you can use the SQFlite's build-in support for doing a raw insert. This means that you can use a SQL string using `rawInsert()`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to map the `List<Object>` in the `items` of [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

```dart
DropdownButton _dropdownButton(List<Object> categoriesList) {
  return DropdownButton(
    value: _selectedValue,
    onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedValue = newValue;
      });
    },
    items: categoriesList
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<Object>>((Object value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<Object>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value.getTxt()), // Replace this with getter for the value you want to display
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```